# Is there some script for updating civicrm for wordpress?

Tags: civicrm-home

I wonder if anybody over there wrote some script (`bash` or `php`) for updating CiviCRM for WordPress with very few (or no) human interventions. I am willing to contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at 'wp civicrm upgrade' using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/)  It has some issues that I keep meaning to investigate, but it's a start.

Comment: The command `wp civicrm upgrade` is broken. The developers are working to fix it.